# Why can't I access information in tbody?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[This is the source code of the website][1]I am doing web scraping with BeautifulSoup but cannot find tr in tbody; there actually is tr in tbody in the source code of the website; however, the find_all function can only return the tr in thead.

link I am scraping on: https://cpj.org/data/killed/?status=Killed&motiveConfirmed%5B%5D=Confirmed&type%5B%5D=Journalist&start_year=1992&end_year=2019&group_by=year

Here are some of my code:

````
```from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```url = "https://cpj.org/data/killed/?status=Killed&motiveConfirmed%5B%5D=Confirmed&type%5B%5D=Journalist&start_year=1992&end_year=2019&group_by=year"
```html = urlopen(url)
```soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
```type(soup)
```tr = soup.find_all("tr")
```print(tr)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFwEV.png
````

Answer (score 2):

Data is requested via API returning json i.e. it is dynamically added so it doesn't appear in your request to the landing page. You can find the API endpoint in the network tab which is used to get the info.

You can alter one of the parameters to a number larger than expected result set then check if you need to make further requests.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://cpj.org/api/datamanager/reports/entries?distinct(personId)&includes=organizations,fullName,location,status,typeOfDeath,charges,startDisplay,mtpage,country,type,motiveConfirmed&sort=fullName&pageNum=1&pageSize=2000&in(status,%27Killed%27)&or(eq(type,%22media%20worker%22),in(motiveConfirmed,%27Confirmed%27))&in(type,%27Journalist%27)&ge(year,1992)&le(year,2019)').json()
```

Otherwise, you can do an initial call and verify how many more requests to make and alter the appropriate paramters in the url. You can see the pageCount is returned.

You can see relevant parts in response here for pagesize 20:

```
{'rowCount': 1343,
 'pageNum': 1,
 'pageSize': '20',
 'pageCount': 68,
```

All the relevant info for a loop to get all results is there.

After altering to larger number you can see the following:

```
'rowCount': 1343,
 'pageNum': 1,
 'pageSize': '2000',
 'pageCount': 1,
```

You can convert to a table using pandas:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://cpj.org/api/datamanager/reports/entries?distinct(personId)&includes=organizations,fullName,location,status,typeOfDeath,charges,startDisplay,mtpage,country,type,motiveConfirmed&sort=fullName&pageNum=1&pageSize=2000&in(status,%27Killed%27)&or(eq(type,%22media%20worker%22),in(motiveConfirmed,%27Confirmed%27))&in(type,%27Journalist%27)&ge(year,1992)&le(year,2019)').json()
df = pd.DataFrame(r['data'])
print(df)
```

---

Sample of df:

[image]

---

Example of checking actual count and make additional request for request of records:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

request_number = 1000

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://cpj.org/api/datamanager/reports/entries?distinct(personId)&includes=organizations,fullName,location,status,typeOfDeath,charges,startDisplay,mtpage,country,type,motiveConfirmed&sort=fullName&pageNum=1&pageSize=' + str(request_number) + '&in(status,%27Killed%27)&or(eq(type,%22media%20worker%22),in(motiveConfirmed,%27Confirmed%27))&in(type,%27Journalist%27)&ge(year,1992)&le(year,2019)').json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(r['data'])
    actual_number = r['rowCount']
    if actual_number > request_number:
        request_number = actual_number - request_number
        r = s.get('https://cpj.org/api/datamanager/reports/entries?distinct(personId)&includes=organizations,fullName,location,status,typeOfDeath,charges,startDisplay,mtpage,country,type,motiveConfirmed&sort=fullName&pageNum=2&pageSize=' + str(request_number) + '&in(status,%27Killed%27)&or(eq(type,%22media%20worker%22),in(motiveConfirmed,%27Confirmed%27))&in(type,%27Journalist%27)&ge(year,1992)&le(year,2019)').json()
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(r['data'])
        final = pd.concat([df,df2])
    else:
        final = df
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Where did you find the link in "r = requests.get('https://cpj.org/api/datamanager/reports/entries?distinct(personId)&includes=organizations,fullName,location,status,typeOfDeath,charges,startDisplay,mtpage,country,type,motiveConfirmed&sort=fullName&pageNum=1&pageSize=2000&in(status,%27Killed%27)&or(eq(type,%22media%20worker%22),in(motiveConfirmed,%27Confirmed%27))&in(type,%27Journalist%27)&ge(year,1992)&le(year,2019)').json() "? What if I want to find unconfirmed deaths or media workers instead of journalists?

Comment: I found it it in the network tab. Open dev tools with f12, refresh the page and inspect the web traffic. You will see the different URIs feeding the page.

Comment: Have a look and see if you can find it and let me know.

Comment: It's a nice solution. This doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

To get the tabular content using the selectors you see by inspecting elements, you can try using this ***[pyppeteer](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/)*** which I've shown below how to work with. The following approach is an asynchronous one. So, I suggest you to go for this unless you find any api to play with:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

url = "https://cpj.org/data/killed/?status=Killed&motiveConfirmed%5B%5D=Confirmed&type%5B%5D=Journalist&start_year=1992&end_year=2019&group_by=year"

async def get_table(link):
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    [page] = await browser.pages()
    await page.goto(link)
    await page.waitForSelector("table.js-report-builder-table tr td")
    for tr in await page.querySelectorAll("table.js-report-builder-table tr"):
        tds = [await page.evaluate('e => e.innerText',td) for td in await tr.querySelectorAll("th,td")]
        print(tds)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(get_table(url))
```

Output are like:

```
['Name', 'Organization', 'Date', 'Location', 'Attack', 'Type of Death', 'Charge']
['Abadullah Hananzai', 'Radio Azadi,Radio Free Europe/Radio Liberty', 'April 30, 2018', 'Afghanistan', 'Killed', 'Murder', '']
['Abay Hailu', 'Agiere', 'February 9, 1998', 'Ethiopia', 'Killed', 'Dangerous Assignment', '']
['Abd al-Karim al-Ezzo', 'Freelance', 'December 21, 2012', 'Syria', 'Killed', 'Crossfire', '']
['Abdallah Bouhachek', 'Révolution et Travail', 'February 10, 1996', 'Algeria', 'Killed', 'Murder', '']
['Abdel Aziz Mahmoud Hasoun', 'Masar Press', 'September 5, 2013', 'Syria', 'Killed', 'Crossfire', '']
['Abdel Karim al-Oqda', 'Shaam News Network', 'September 19, 2012', 'Syria', 'Killed', 'Murder', '']
```